# Mysql return null if subquery returns null

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hy guys, sometimes my subquery return null which is ok, it should return null, but in those cases i would like my "parent select" to return null.

Is that possible?

And if yes, then how?

Heres the code:

```
SELECT 
    `company`.`companyID`,
    `company`.`companyName`, 
    `company`.`companyName`, 
    `company`.`companyEmail`, 
    `company`.`contactEmail`,
    `company`.`companyTel`,                 
    (
        SELECT 
            `package_map`.`szekhely_endDate`
        FROM 
            `package_map` 
        WHERE 
            `package_map`.`companyID` = `company`.`companyID`
        AND 
            `package_map`.`active` = 1
        AND 
            `package_map`.`szekhely_endDate` > NOW()
        ORDER BY 
            `package_map`.`szekhely_endDate` DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) as endDate,
CASE 
    WHEN endDate = NULL

FROM 
    `company` 
WHERE 
    `company`.`companyBase` = 'some address' 
AND 
    `company`.`szekhely_check_out` = 0
```

Comment: JOIN with the subquery instead of putting it in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordinary INNER JOIN between the two tables. If there's no matching rows in the `package_map` table, there won't be a row in the result. To get the latest `endDate`, use the `MAX()` function.

```
SELECT 
    `company`.`companyID`,
    `company`.`companyName`, 
    `company`.`companyName`, 
    `company`.`companyEmail`, 
    `company`.`contactEmail`,
    `company`.`companyTel`,                 
    MAX(package_map.szekhely_endDate) AS endDate
FROM company
INNER JOIN package_map ON `package_map`.`companyID` = `company`.`companyID`
WHERE 
    `company`.`companyBase` = 'some address' 
AND 
    `company`.`szekhely_check_out` = 0
AND 
    `package_map`.`active` = 1
AND 
    `package_map`.`szekhely_endDate` > NOW()
GROUP BY `company`.`companyID`
```

Comment: i get Unknown column 'company.companyID' in 'where clause' error

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that it was a correlated subquery. I need to rethink this.

Comment: Ok please let me know if you got something