# Return null if top two rows are same in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a use case where I want to return null in MySQL if the top two rows have the same value.

```
SELECT FACILITY_ID, INVENTORY FROM FACILITY
ORDER BY INVENTORY DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Here is the same date

```
FACILITY_ID | INVENTORY

1 | 10

2 | 10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql return null if subquery returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537256/mysql-return-null-if-subquery-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `LAG()` Function. Here's the documentation:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/

Comment: I have MYSQL version 5.7.29 Please suggest any solution for this version. Window function starts from 8.0 and above version